# How to show Toolbar actions batch count in flutter?

Tags: flutter, toolbar

I am working in an cart kind of application, where I need to show cart item counts. How to show item counts in Toolbar actions. I surfed lot couldn't find the solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add a button with image and text as `Action` to `AppBar` widget. Then whenever you adding the item, you need to update the text inside the Action. Here a working simple example:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(new MaterialApp(
    title: "Sample",
    home: new Home(),
  ));
}

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  // save the total of the item here.
  int _total = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(

      // add the AppBar to the page
      appBar: new AppBar(
        actions: <Widget>[

          // Add a FlatButton as an Action for the AppBar
          FlatButton(
            onPressed: () => {},
            child: Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                Icon(Icons.shop),
                Text("Total $_total")
              ],
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
      floatingActionButton: new FloatingActionButton(
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
        onPressed: _increaseTotal,
        tooltip: "Add",
      ),
    );
  }

  // increase the total item whenever you click the FloatingActionBar
  void _increaseTotal() {
    setState(() {
      _total++;
    });
  }
}
```